# Adding int A plus the product of the individual numbers A is made of

Tags: java, parseint

Okay so I am writing a program that will ask the user for two numbers.

```
n = the starting number of a sequence.
k = the length of the sequence.
```

I want the next number to equal the previous number plus the product of that number's digits.

this is what i have. I want to use a parseInt but not sure how

```
public class John

{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int initial_num, output_seq;

        while(true)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter n and k: ");
            initial_num = sc.nextInt();
            output_seq = sc.nextInt();

            if(initial_num != 0 || output_seq != 0)
                System.out.println(nextNum(initial_num, output_seq));
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    static int nextNum(int input, int output)
    {
        int first = input;
        int seq_num = output;
        int next_num = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < seq_num; k++)
        {
            next_num = first + ( * );
        }
        return next_num;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure how write the product.

Comment: I don't really see a need for parseInt because you have no Strings in use. What exactly do you mean by the product of the numbers digits?

Comment: Why do you need `parseInt`?  If you're thinking that you want to convert the `int` to a `String` so that you can look at all the digits, that's the opposite of parsing (`parseInt` converts a `String` to an `int`).  Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I just thought converting them to a string would help.

Comment: OK, then `parseInt` isn't what you want.  Try [`Integer.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString--), e.g. `String digits = Integer.toString(someNumber);`.

Comment: Also, if you look at the characters in the string, be aware that the `char` values of each character will be 48, 49, 50, etc., not 0, 1, 2.  If you convert the integer to a string and then get a `char` from it, you can convert it to the digit value with `someCharacter - '0'`.

Comment: i'm still a little confused what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate the product of the digits of a number, use the properties of decimal numbers.  In other words, divide by ten and take the remainder (modulo 10).  There is no need to turn it to a string and take individual characters and convert those to integers.

```
public long digitProduct (long anInteger) throws Exception {
    if (anInteger <= 0) {
        throw new Exception ("digitProduct:  input integer " + anInteger +
            " is less than or equal to zero.");
    }
    long product = 1;
    do {
        product = product * (anInteger % 10);  // modulo 10 is last digit.
        anInteger = anInteger / 10;  // Shifts out last digit.
    } while (anInteger > 0);
    return product;
} // digitProduct (long)
```

Use longs because the product could get large very quickly.  Consider using BigInteger.

Comment: I think it's more likely that the product would become 0 very quickly than that it would get too large very quickly, but that's just a guess and I haven't done a statistical analysis.

Comment: Insightful.  For some reason I neglected to consider the zero digit !